# Power series of $\frac{1}{(z+3)^3}$ at $z_0=-1$.

Tags: calculus, power-series

Power series of $\frac{1}{(z+3)^3}$ at $z_0=-1$.

My attempt:$$\frac{1}{(z+2)^3}=\frac{1}{8}\left(1-\frac{z}{2}\right)^{-3}=\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\begin{pmatrix} -3 \\ k \end{pmatrix}\cdot \left(-\frac{z}{2}\right)^k$$ How can I implement the center of the series at $z_0=-1$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{(z+3)^3}=(2+(z+1))^{-3}=2^{-3}(1+(z+1)/2)^{-3}$. Use the [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) $(1+x)^{-3}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-3}{n}x^n$, compose it with $x=(z+1)/2$ and multiply by $2^{-3}$. For an alternative to using the binomial series directly, you could take a couple of derivatives of the geometric series $(1+x)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, with expressions of the type $\frac{1}{(z+a)^k}$ it's useful to use the [geometric series formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula) to get the power series. First, notice that
$$
\frac{d^2}{dz^2} \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{z+3}\right) = \frac{1}{(z+3)^3} \tag{1}
$$
On the other hand, using the geometric series formula $\sum_{k\ge 0} \color{purple}{r}^k = \frac{1}{1-\color{purple}{r}}$ we get:
$$
\frac{1}{z+3} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1 - \left(\color{purple}{-\frac{z+1}{2}} \right)}\right) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k \ge 0}\left(\color{purple}{-\frac{z+1}{2}} \right)^k \tag{2}
$$
Thus
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{(z+3)^3} & \overset{\color{blue}{(1)}}{=} \frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dz^2} \left(\frac{1}{z+3}\right) \\
& \overset{\color{blue}{(2)}}{=} \frac{1}{\color{green}{2}}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}  \frac{1}{\color{green}{2}} \sum_{k \ge 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}(z-(-1))^k \\
 &=   \sum_{k \ge 2}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{k+\color{green}{2}}}\frac{d^2}{dz^2} (z-(-1))^k \\
 &=   \sum_{k \ge 2}\frac{(-1)^kk(k-1)}{2^{k+2}} (z-(-1))^{k-2} \\
 &\overset{\color{blue}{n = k-2}}{=}  \boxed{ \sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n(n+1)(n+2)}{2^{n+4}} (z-(-1))^n} 
\end{align*}
As a bonus, using this method you also get the radius of convergence for free. Since the geometric series converges for $\lvert \color{purple}{r} \rvert < 1$, in our case this means that the series converges when
$$
\Big\lvert\color{purple}{-\frac{z+1}{2}} \Big\rvert < 1 \implies |z-(-1)| < \underbrace{2}_{\text{Radius}}
$$